# Where does a virus go when it is found using clamAV

Tags: antivirus, clamav

When clamAV detects a virus during a scan where does it go? Will it ask me to remove it or do i have to remove it myself?

Answer (score 2):

You will be given the options to keep, quarantine or delete them. If you keep them, then of course you can physically delete them.

When you chose to keep, you can also choose if you don't want to be alerted to these again, or if it can flag them next scan.